# ChartJS - Gradient color overlap

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I have a line chart with 2 datasets, and both of them are filled with a gradient. The issue is that the gradients overlap, which changes the color of the 'bottom' dataset significantly.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/SimeriaIonut/pen/ydjdLz

My gradients and their positions:

```
var gradientFillPlanned = ctx.createLinearGradient(250.000, 0.000, 150.000, 500.000);
gradientFillPlanned.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0.6)");
gradientFillPlanned.addColorStop(1, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0.0)");

var gradientFillActual = ctx.createLinearGradient(250.000, 0.000, 150.000, 500.000);
gradientFillActual.addColorStop(0, "rgba(244, 144, 128, 0.6)");
gradientFillActual.addColorStop(1, "rgba(244, 144, 128, 0.0)");
```

Is there a way to only render the 'top' dataset only to the point where the bottom dataset starts? Like a css mask or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: It's due to the transparency in `rgba` such as `0.6`

Comment: @AswinKumar Any way to get around it? Like masking?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the transparency in `rgba` such as `0.6`. You can try this

```
var gradientFillActual = ctx.createLinearGradient(250.0, 0.0, 150.0, 500.0);
gradientFillActual.addColorStop(0, "rgba(249,190,240, 1)");
gradientFillActual.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,255, 1)");
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/NZzPPM)